# Three finger dragging on ubuntu-touch tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, drag-and-drop

I think it appeared with the last system upgrade (or I hadn't remarked it before): a zone 1/5th of the size of my screen on the right hand (when in horizontal position), inviting me to drag applications there with a three finger swipe.

The text is "Drag using 3 fingers any application from one window to the other."

I don't understand what this is good for. The rest of the screen is not resizing, the underlying app is partly hidden under the side zone and therefore unusable.
It would be nice to be able to have two apps in parralel. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 2):

I have only come across this a few times and each time, I have not had much success with it. The first time I came across this was by mistake and I had no idea how to get it back to normal, as the three fingers didn't seem to work. Now I seem to be able to tap on the screen three times and the side panel appears. Once apps/screens are on there, it seems almost impossible to get them off again, without closing them down. I do agree that having more than one app there, would be good, however I think more development in this is needed and possibly that will come in later releases. Possibly log this in Launchpad.